# How can I call all the signal R events without explicitly invoking them using hubconnection.On method

Tags: angular, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

We have a API with SignalR implementation for chat, reminder and so on. I want to invoke all of methods on my client portal that's on angular without passing hub method names explicitly through hub connection "On" method like below.

```
 this.hubConnection.on('SignalMessageReceived', (payload: any) => {
      // business logic goes here
    });
```

[MS Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client.hubconnection.on?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-signalr-client-hubconnection-on(system-string-system-type()-system-func((system-object()-system-object-system-threading-tasks-task))-system-object))

Answer (score 0):

You have to do declare an interface for your methods and a hub:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyApp.Hubs
{
  public interface IChat
  {
    Task SignalMessageReceived(string message);        
  }

  public class ChatHub : Hub<IChat>
  {       
   // here you can put methods that can be called from angular
  }
}
```

Then in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<MyApp.Hubs.ChatHub>("api/hubs/chat");
        });
```

Now when you want to invoke the method you get a reference to IHubContext<ChatHub, IChat> hubcontext through dependency injection. For example in a controller you can do:

```
IChat hub = hubcontext.Clients.All;
await  hub.SignalMessageReceived("Hello");
```